# Elegant way to copy all files from a folder tree onto one folder preferably using robocopy?

Tags: robocopy

I have the following job which I would like to run: I have a folder with numerous subfolders containing about 50,000 files which I would like to copy onto a single folder. I thought the most straight forward way would be using the search function in windows explorer, searching all files of the folder by using *.* and then droping the files into the target folder. However, this only causes trouble and finally the number of files in the new folder is not the same than in the original folder. After some research on command line tools I found robocopy which seemingly is quite good but I did not manage to get what I want. I manage to mirror the folder or to move all files but the folder structure will be retained using the standard commands as for example

```
robocopy C:\originalFolder C:\targetfolder /e /move
```

does anybody have an idea how to approach this question further? I am not bound to robocopy but what I really like is the possibility to write a log file.

Thanks a lot. Herbie

Answer (score 0):

I now tried

```
for /r C:\originalFolder %f in (*) do @xcopy "%f" C:\targetFolder /Y /H
```

a modification of a script I found which does basically what I wish, but still the number of files in the target folder is >1000 less than in the original folder. Does anybody have an idea?